# KnockoutJS How can I create cleaner and shorter nested loop?

Tags: knockout.js

I've created a nested loop for each month of the year and pushed this to the UI. How can I make my code less verbose and make my nested loop cleaner?

The data comes from a SharePoint endpoint (odata).

The logic is real world events being displayed in the UI. These are in the Observable array and each belongs to a calendar month of the year as well as having a date field. I've tried with the January example below but it's getting verbose and need to do this for all the months. Can it be made shorter?

Controller:

```
var months = [{name: 'January', value: '01'},{name: 'February', value: '02'}]; 

    if (typeof filteredJan !== null && filteredJan.length > 0) {
      for(var i=0;i<filteredJan.length;i++){
        filteredJan[0].Month = 'JANUARY';
        filteredJan[i].StartDate = this.formatDate(filteredJan[i].StartDate);
        filteredJan[i].EndDate = this.formatDate(filteredJan[i].EndDate);

          if(filteredJan[i].StartDate[i].substr(0,2) === months[i].value){ 
              console.log(months[i].name);
              this.filteredDates(months)
          }
          debugger

        this.locationsFilteredJan(filteredJan);
      }
    }



    if (typeof filteredFeb !== null && filteredFeb.length > 0) {
      for(var i=0;i<filteredFeb.length;i++){
        //
        filteredFeb[i].StartDate = this.formatDate(filteredFeb[i].StartDate);
        filteredFeb[i].EndDate = this.formatDate(filteredFeb[i].EndDate);
        this.locationsFilteredFeb(filteredFeb);
      }
    }
```

Client:

```
<table >
   <thead>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: locationsFilteredJan">
         <tr>  
             <td data-bind="text: Month"></td>
         </tr>    
      </tbody>
         <tr>
             <th>Event</th><th>Start Date</th><th>End Date</th> 
             <th>Location</th>
             <th>Book</th>
         </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: locationsFilteredJan">
      <tr>  
          <td data-bind="text: Title"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: $parent.formatDate(Start_x0020_Date)"></td>       
          <td data-bind="text: $parent.formatDate(End_x0020_Date)"></td>      
          <td data-bind="text: Location"></td>
          <td><a data-bind="text: Id, attr: { href: 
'https://web.powerapps.com/apps/?event_id='+ Id }">Book</a></td>
      </tr>    
   </tbody>
</table>
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>  
         <td>FEBRUARY</td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: locationsFilteredFeb">
     <tr>  
         <td data-bind="text: Title"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: $parent.formatDate(Start_x0020_Date)"></td>       
         <td data-bind="text: $parent.formatDate(End_x0020_Date)"></td>      
         <td data-bind="text: Location"></td>
         <td><a data-bind="text: Id, attr: { href: 
   'https://web.powerapps.com/apps/?event_id='+ Id }">Book</a></td>
     </tr>    
   </tbody>
</table>`
```

I believe the best way would be dynamic for loop of months that reads from new Date and then pushes each month (January, February etc.) to UI based on current Array position's date (filteredJan[i].StartDate[i].substr(0,2)). The current Array position contains events each with a date and the calendar month pulled out needs to match this date in Array and sort each one under a correct month in UI. Currently, it works as mentioned but it's too verbose and needs it more simple and faster Performance.

**NOTE UPDATE:**
Can get it to work with simple objects like so:

```
var events =  [
    {name: 'Skiing',          value: '02/01/2018'},
    {name: 'Skydiving',       value: '28/02/2018'},
    {name: 'Sledging',        value: '15/01/2018'}]; 
var months = [
    {name: 'JANUARY',        value: '09/01/2018'},
    {name: 'FEBRUARY',       value: '19/02/2018'}]; 

var companyUsers = {}// hashmap of users using companyId as keys

events.forEach(function(user){
  var id= user.value.substring(3, 5);
  //console.log(id);
  companyUsers[id] = companyUsers[id]||[]; 
  companyUsers[id].push(user)
});
var text = "";
// map new array based on each subscription
var res = months.map(function(sub){
  sub.events = companyUsers[sub.value.substring(3, 5)] || [];      
  text += sub.events[sub] + "<br>"; 
  return sub;

});

//push to view
console.log(res)
```

But not like so:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
        <th scope="col">End Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Booking</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr><td><h4>JANUARY</h4> </td></tr>  
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: locationsFilteredMonths">
        <tr>  
          <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
         </tr>    
    </tbody>   
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: $parent.data[locationsFilteredMonths]">
              <tr>  
                <td data-bind="text: Title"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $parent.formatDate(Start_x0020_Date)"></td>       
                <td data-bind="text: $parent.formatDate(End_x0020_Date)"></td>      
                <td data-bind="text: Location"></td>
                <td><a data-bind="text: Id, attr: { href: 'https://web.powerapps.com/apps/?event_id='+ Id }">Book</a></td>
              </tr>    
          </tbody>    
  </table>
```

Controller:

```
 var months = [
    {name: 'JANUARY',        value: '01'},
    {name: 'FEBRUARY',       value: '02'},
    {name: 'MARCH',           value: '03'},
    {name: 'APRIL',           value: '04'},
    {name: 'MAY',             value: '05'},
    {name: 'JUNE',            value: '06'},
    {name: 'JULYS',           value: '07'},
    {name: 'AUGUST',          value: '08'},
    {name: 'SEPTEMBER',       value: '09'},
    {name: 'OCTOBER',         value: '10'},
    {name: 'NOVEMBER',        value: '11'},
    {name: 'DECEMBER',        value: '12'}]; 

var eventsHash = {};
    //format API dates
     if (typeof filteredEvents !== null && filteredEvents.length > 0) {
        var i:any;
        for(i=0;i<filteredEvents.length;i++){
          filteredEvents[i].StartDate = this.formatDate(filteredEvents[i].StartDate);
          filteredEvents[i].EndDate = this.formatDate(filteredEvents[i].EndDate);
        }
      }

     filteredEvents.forEach(function(event){
        //get position of month and use as id
        var monthStr = event.StartDate.substring(3, 5);
        console.log(monthStr);
        eventsHash[monthStr] = eventsHash[monthStr]||[]; 
        eventsHash[monthStr].push(event);
    });

    var filteredMonths = months.map(function(sub){
      sub.value = eventsHash[sub.name];      
      //text += sub.events[sub] + "<br>"; 
      return sub;
    });

    //for each month show events
    this.locationsFilteredMonths(filteredMonths);
    this.locationsFilteredYears(filteredEvents);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to transform your data into an object with the month names as keys, like so:

```
{
    'January': [
        {
            Id: '',
            Title: 'Foo',
            Start_x0020_Date: '',
            End_x0020_Date: '',
            Location: ''
        },
        {
            Id: '',
            Title: 'Foo',
            Start_x0020_Date: '',
            End_x0020_Date: '',
            Location: ''
        }
    ],
    'February': [
        {
            Id: '',
            Title: 'Foo',
            Start_x0020_Date: '',
            End_x0020_Date: '',
            Location: ''
        },
        {
            Id: '',
            Title: 'Foo',
            Start_x0020_Date: '',
            End_x0020_Date: '',
            Location: ''
        }
    ]
}
```

How to do that exactly would depend on your source data, but I'm assuming you're getting it from some API and it's just one big collection of events. It would just take one single loop.

Then your template would simply look like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(data), as: 'month' } -->
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>  
         <td data-bind="text: month"></td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: $parent.data[month]">
     <tr>  
         <td data-bind="text: Title"></td>
         <td data-bind="text: $parents[1].formatDate(Start_x0020_Date)"></td>       
         <td data-bind="text: $parents[1].formatDate(End_x0020_Date)"></td>      
         <td data-bind="text: Location"></td>
         <td><a data-bind="text: Id, attr: { href: 'https://web.powerapps.com/apps/?event_id='+ Id }">Book</a></td>
     </tr>    
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Edit:

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/5yL0knm9/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried (updated my question with code) using a hash table to do so but still cannot get elements pushed into my hash children. I can only get this to work in browser via simple objects (also updated in question). Should that be $parent[1], and not $parents[1]? Although this latter bit I don't think will resolve and the mapping(with hash or not) carries most importance.

Comment: Without seeing your code in action, hard to tell where it's going wrong. I added a link to a working example to my post that might help you along. Feel free to do the same if you're still having issues, it'll make it easier to help you.